# Dozer and Spring integration

Tags: spring, dozer

EDIT : A new lib has been introduced which clarify the thing for new versions

> Since version 5.5.0 Spring integration comes within additional module
>   dozer-spring.

---

Hi there I'm relatively new to Dozer and Spring  and a bit confused about how to put that in place.

From the dozer website : http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/usage.html

> **Spring integration**
>   ...

```
<bean id="mapper" class="org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper">
  <property name="mappingFiles">
    <list>
      <value>dozer-global-configuration.xml</value>            
      <value>dozer-bean-mappings.xml</value>
      <value>more-dozer-bean-mappings.xml</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Now from http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/springintegration.html :

```
<bean class="org.dozer.spring.DozerBeanMapperFactoryBean">
    <property name="mappingFiles" value="classpath*:/*mapping.xml"/>
    <property name="customConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.dozer.converters.CustomConverter"/>      
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="eventListeners">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.dozer.listeners.EventListener"/>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="factories">
        <map>
            <entry key="id" value-ref="bean-factory-ref"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

So I'm not really sure which way I should use it. My objectives is to have a mapper object in my business classes that will convert `Business Objects` to `DTO` (and reversely).
So I think it just should be a basic Dependency Injection ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both are valid approaches, just inject this mapper as a dependency in the service class responsible for mapping, eg:

```
@Service
public class MyMappingService{
 @Autowired DozerBeanMapper dozerBeanMapper;
}
```

With DozerBeanMapperFactoryBean the approach along these lines should work:

```
<bean class="org.dozer.spring.DozerBeanMapperFactoryBean">
....
</bean>
```

This returns a mapper instance, so just inject in a mapper type this way:

```
@Service
public class MyMappingService{
 @Autowired Mapper dozerBeanMapper;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind telling me the difference between using the Bean Mapper Factory Bean instead of the mapper directly ? Maybe configuration options ? Thanks anyway, I'm going on a test with the first proposition

Comment: DozerBeanMapperFactoryBean is a Spring factory bean, which returns Mapper instances and sounds like it is more suited for Spring dependency injection, I have modified the answer with an example.

Comment: I finally went with the DozerBeanMapper solution. Thanks.