# Spring @Autowired bean is null

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, dozer

I am trying to use Dozer to map between two object types. I had a look at [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323282/dozer-and-spring-integration)

I have below code to get the dozer mapper from the spring context. For some reason I am getting the mapper always as null. Why does mapper always gets null? Why doesn't spring instantiate that bean?
I couldn't figure out the reason so far. I may be doing a silly mistake, couldn't figure out so far though.

```
@Component
public class AccountConverterImpl implements Converter<AccountOutput, Account> {

@Autowired
Mapper mapper;

@Override
public AccountOutput convert(Account data) {

    return mapper.map(data, AccountOutput.class);

}
```

Here is my spring context file

```
...
<!-- bean for dozer mapping-->
<bean id="mapper" class="org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper">
    <property name="mappingFiles">
        <list>
            <value>dto.mapping.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Don't you have to explicitly declare `Mapper` as a bean in your spring context?

Comment: If the mapper is null you aren't using Spring to instantiate an instance of the `AccountConverterImpl`. Don't construct instances yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Don't even try.

`mapper.map(data, AccountOutput.class)`
method calls Converters for `AccountOutput.class`, that calls `convert(Account data)` method. `convert` calls `map` method again.